# combining tenses in "{Have/Did} you {see/seen} that I {have/had} sent you the report

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

I was told that most of them don't work. But I don't understand why.

> 1. Have you seen that I have sent you the report?
> 2. Did you see that I have sent you the report?
> 3. Did you see that I sent you the report?
> 4. Have you seen that I sent you the report?
> 5. Did you see that I had sent you the report?

My interpretations:

1. May talk about several occasions. "Have you seen (once or more than once that I have sent you the report several times recently?)"
2. I am not sure about this one, but I can see this: Tony Delaney said he has written to seven schools suspected of - the same combination of tenses.
3. OK
4. This is a variation: "Have you seen the report which I sent you?"
5. Not sure.

Comment: All 5 of your examples are syntactically valid. Almosat cedrtainly #3 would be by far the most *common* version, but so far as I can see it's just a stylistic choice. They all *mean* exactly the same thing.

Comment: You are asking for us to review all those tenses and your usage. There are tons of answers here that deal with all those tenses. That said, your analysis of 1) is incorrect. It merely tell us it was in the past but not specifically when. One of the main drivers of the present perfect.

Comment: If my analysis of 1 is incorrect how would you convey the idea otherwise? I mean "I want to know if the person has seen my multiple emails containing the report. I sent you it on Monday, on Tuesday twice and on Friday. So, Have you seen that I have sent you... If you disagree, provide your option.

Comment: @user1425 I am being generous by ignoring that last comment of yours. OK, so I will REPEAT what I said: One of the main drivers of the present perfect tense is meaning that something occurred in the past without saying WHEN. I went to the movies **last night**. VERSUS I haven't been to the movies recently.  You might want to look up: to be the driver for or of something.  If **want to express** that something happened in the past (in relation to the present) without specifying WHEN, I use the PP.

Comment: @user1425: You are supposed to ask **one** question, not **five**. You are also attacking other users who know far more about English than you do. Not cool.

Comment: Cross-post from WordReference: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-choice-of-the-tense.3798323/

Comment: (If I dare stick my nose in) - To indicate that you have sent the report several times, say "I sent it several times" or "I kept [on] sending it."

Answer (score 1):

I think all of them are grammatically correct.

**1. Have you seen that I have sent you the report?**

A possible context for this one is this:

I promised to the person 2 minutes ago to send the report. I know they have been waiting for it since then. I am calling them now and wondering if they have seen the report which I have just sent. I am going to go on talking on the matter of the report in the event of my recipient's positive answer.

**2. Did you see that I have sent you the report?**

It means basically the same as the first one. But, the time of their seeing the report might not be so recent as in the first one. Maybe it was several hours ago or even days. But for me, it's important to bring to their attention that the report has been sent to them. I might discuss the report later on.

**3. Did you see that I sent you the report?**

It might happen relatively long ago or recently. I am not willing to discuss it further. I just need a plain answer about the status of the report.

**4. Have you seen that I sent you the report?**

The person has been denying having seen the report. I've been insisting that it was sent and asking to double-check. It's a crucial matter for me whether the person has seen the report.

**5. Did you see that I had sent you the report?**

Basically, it means almost the same as 3.